# How do I respond to window resize in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How can I get notified when the window is resized in PySimpleGUI?

I have a window that enables resize events, but I'm not finding a way to move the elements around when that resize occurs, so my window renames top left centered the same size when the window changes size.

Here is the basic code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Button('Save')]]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', 
                   layout,
                   default_element_size=(12, 1),
                   resizable=True)  # this is the change

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Save':
        print('clicked save')

    if event == sg.WIN_MAXIMIZED:  # I just made this up, and it does not work. :)
        window.maximize()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind `"<Configure>"` event to check zoomed event.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Window normal', size=(30, 1), key='Status')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True)
window.bind('<Configure>', "Configure")
status = window['Status']

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Configure':
        if window.TKroot.state() == 'zoomed':
            status.update(value='Window zoomed and maximized !')
        else:
            status.update(value='Window normal')

window.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding tkinter events to windows results in callback on change of windows size

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


layout = [[sg.Button('Save')]]
window = sg.Window('Window Title',
                   layout,
                   default_element_size=(12, 1),
                   resizable=True,finalize=True)  # this is the chang
window.bind('<Configure>',"Event")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Save':
        print('clicked save')

    if event == "Event":
        print(window.size)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        print("I am done")
        break
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning window.size. It could be used to create a non tkinter specific solution (with window.read(timeout=100) and checking the size for changes)